# Show Drupal nodes (news) mixed with facebook posts sorted by date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-7

As in title I would like to build news page / block where post from facebook are mixed with post on my site like

1. today 11 am | post from facebook txt | attached photo / video
2. today 10 am | drupal node content | drupal fields
3. yesterday 9 pm | drupal node content | drupal fields
4. yesterday 5 pm | post from facebook txt | attached photo / video

etc.

My idea is to save unique FB posts to unique Drupal nodes (no duplicates) and then use Views Module to get it done, but I cannot find a module which can pull and save FB post.

Can you help me? Please :-)

Answer (score 0):

- I'm sure you have to check for Facebook API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post)

  - Don't forget to check modules like [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_wall)
  - If you want manual solution in drupal 7 you have to implement APIs requests using cron or some submit function